# Sum float from txt file with a row of strings followed by an integer c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to add up the minutes of a manual input song library and can't figure out how to pull the float from every 4th row until the end of the list to make a sum. This list can be added to, so it is not a set number of rows to pull data from. 
Is it possible to do this the way I have the txt file formatted? Other functions use this file for display purposes so I am trying to keep the formatting the same.

This is the data stored in the text file "songLibrary.txt"

```
Title
Album
Artist
1.5
Title
Album
Artist
1.7
Title
Album
Artist
3.1
```

Comment: To answer the only question that's asked here: yes, it is possible to do this the way the file is formatted, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep reading until you hit end-of-file.  One thing to note is that end-of-file cannot be detected until a read of the file has occurred.  This is why the test is in both the `while()` and the `if()` below that.  Theoretically it should be checked after every read, but since we're throwing away data, there's no real point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin = fopen(  "songLibrary.txt", "rt" );
    double sum = 0.0;

    if (fin != NULL)
    {
        char buffer[128];

        while ( !feof( fin ) && !ferror( fin ) )
        {
            // File format:
            //     Title
            //     Album
            //     Artist
            //     some-number
            fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin );  // read and junk 3 lines of text
            fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin );
            fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin );

            fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin ); // We should have just read a number
            if ( !feof( fin ) && !ferror( fin ) )
            {
                double value = strtod( buffer, NULL );  // TODO check for errors
                sum += value;
            }
        }
        fclose(fin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very C-ish C++, but it illustrates the algorithm.